# Can You Transport a Brick House with Only Drawmij's Instant Summons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

> Drawmij's Instant Summons. You touch an object weighing 10 pounds or less whose longest dimension is 6 feet or less. The spell leaves an invisible mark on its surface and invisibly inscribes the name of the item on the sapphire you use as the material component. Each time you cast this spell, you must use a different sapphire.

Since the limit on objects is 10 lb or less, and the longest dimension being 6' or less, does that mean you could, theoretically and impractically, summon an entire brick house, or other piece of construction made from smaller individual parts, into your hand by having enough sapphires as there are pieces?

Comment: You know, a sensible wizard would just use Galder's Tower.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### No.

Per [the spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons):

> At any time thereafter, you can use your action to speak the item’s name and crush the sapphire. The item instantly appears in your hand regardless of physical or planar distances, and the spell ends.

It takes your action to crush a *single* sapphire, so even if your DM allowed this (the spell does not give any indication summoning parts of a larger object would be legal), you'd be summoning the composite "object" piecemeal, one piece every six seconds, and it's definitely not going to be intact. It would also be ridiculously expensive, what with each individual summoning requiring the sacrifice of a 1000 GP sapphire.

And before you think to work around this by stacking all the castings on a single sapphire you can crush to summon all pieces at once, the spell explicitly forbids that:

> Each time you cast this spell, you must use a different sapphire.

Comment: Even if they allowed you to crush all the sapphires simultaneously, a brick house appearing "in your hand" sounds a lot like something or perhaps *someone* will not come out of it intact.

Comment: @Kryomaani: Yeah, it's a terrible idea even if it worked on multiple levels (for a "house" of the most modest size you're talking at least 10K GP; you could probably buy hundreds of equivalent houses for that price, and/or just combine Fabricate/Wall of Stone/Stone Shape to build whatever you like on site, or Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion for single-spell, generally non-permanent but comprehensive shelter).

Comment: So that means you could destroy a building by suddenly removing its load-bearing beams with Drawmij's Instant Summons. Duly noted. There's probably something better to do that though.

Comment: @JThompson: You could also destroy the building by just, you know, *destroying* a load bearing beam (with a max weight of 10 lbs, and max dimensions of 6', it's probably not load-bearing), rather than coming up with complicated ways to spend 1+ minutes marking it so you can get teleport it at a cost of *1000 GP* later. Even if "ability to mess up later* is important, you could just take a shaving of wood from it and **Teleport** alchemist's fire to it with 100% accuracy up to six months later. **Instant Summons** is protection for *irreplaceable* items, it's too expensive otherwise.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's true. +1.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to upgrade from a brick house to a tower, and it will save you a ton of sapphires casting [Drawmij's Instant Summons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/drawmijs-instant-summons).
Using the gold you would spend on those sapphires, purchase an [Instant Fortress](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4663-instant-fortress) instead. You now have a magic item that with a single command, will become a 20' x 20' by 30' tall tower with all the amenities of a house.

You will save a small fortune and a ton of time casting once as opposed to piece by piece and then having to build it yourself.

Comment: Very valid. I wasn't looking for a portable abode necessarily, but trying to plumb the details of Drawmij's Instant Summons. I appreciate the work-around though. +1.